# Windows - send all traffic via my own proxy server

Tags: windows, proxy

I have my own proxy server at home but I am not sure how can I "connect" to it with my computer so all the traffic would go via the proxy, there are many proxy programs but there is no program that would allow you to type in your own IP and PORT of the proxy.

Does anybody know one ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a separate program, as your web browser itself has the proxy settings where you can type in the IP and port to use. FireFox, Chrome, Opera, Edge all have these settings in their preferences. 
For Internet Explorer, you get to the settings through "Internet Options" from Control Panel or Internet Explorer either one.

Depending on your network setup, you can also set your firewall settings so that all traffic is forced through your proxy server, regardless of your browser settings, but this is probably more advanced than you want to go right now.

Comment: I need to redirect traffic from all programs, not just browser.

Comment: Then you need to use firewall rules, like I mentioned, or a VPN, like phosplait mentioned, or another device that is between your PC and the proxy server that can direct all IP traffic to where you want. Normally a proxy server only applies to browser traffic. If you are getting into other traffic types, then it can become very very complex. OpenVPN is a good VPN solution if  you want to go that route. Or you can use pfSense or a similar firewall distro on a computer that sits on your network as a redirector.

Comment: Or if your proxy server supports routing/forwarding packets (which it must if it's able to proxy _all_ traffic) then you can just point your default gateway to the IP of your proxy server. You do this in your network settings.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish is probably more suitable for a VPN setup. Even the native Windows VPN client has a setting that will essentially setup your computer's routing tables to forward all traffic through the VPN.

Otherwise, you are best doing as ruhnet suggested and configuring your browser to use the proxy.